# Working dropdown menu in Wordpress "dropped" out function/links

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, portfolio

I followed this tutorial to a tee: http://mysitemyway.com/docs/index.php/Collapsible_sidebar_menus

My site here: http://inlightimage.com/

Links with # 'photography', 'design', and 'teaching' drop down beautifully and responsive, the pages listed below are not clickable/linked. Nothing moves.

If possible, I would love to know where I went wrong in copying and pasting.

I added to custom CSS:

```
.menu .dropdown .sub-menu { display: none; }
```

I added to custom JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.menu .dropdown a').click(function(e){  
          e.preventDefault();
          if (jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').hide();
          } else {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').show();
          }
     });
});
```

Perhaps it is not compatible with my theme? (Moka theme by ElmaStudio)

Thank you very much for any direction/help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing:

```
jQuery('.menu .dropdown a').click(function(e){
```

To:

```
jQuery('.menu .dropdown > a').click(function(e){
```

It looks like the selector was too generic and applying the preventDefault to all links instead of parent items.

Comment: After the page is clicked onto, the menu snaps back to it's original pre drop down state. Is there any way fix the menu in place once the user has clicked the drop down and revealed the sub pages? I.e, prevented from collapsing unless the category is clicked again to 'clean' and 'condense' it again? If possible, thank you.

Comment: You could change the output to include a class for the active page and then detect that in jQuery. You could even use entirely jQuery to achieve this but it's beyond the scope of the original question. Have a go at it and if you get stuck post your code.